# JTextPane Displaying English character along with urdu

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

[image]

That's the image of my Urdu text editor.

As you can see, when i try to display the Urdu characters, the English characters also show up.

I am implementing my own keyboard listener for this text component and when ever there is a key press, I get that key as a character, translate it to its corresponding Urdu, insert it in textPane using `document.insertString()` method, but the English characters are displayed automatically as well.

What can i do so that this English character does not display in the component and it display only the Urdu characters which I translate from English?

---

@Harrison F :Here is the code you are asking for

```
char b = e.getKeyChar();// e is the object of class KeyEvent
char c = Translate.translateToUrdu(b);// its my own class for translation
s = s+c;// converting the character to string.
doc.insertString(carretPos,s,null);       // inserting into the document
s = ""; //setting the string object to "" so that next time i can use it again.
```

**EDIT :** My problem is solved by implementing a class that extends `DocumentFilter` and then overriding its `insertString` and `replaceString` methods. Now there exists another problem, that is, my enter key is not working now and some other control keys like ctrl. How can i make such keys to work in my document filter?

Comment: Can you please show the code for your `document.insertString()`? I suspect that you are not stripping out the original character and thus it gets appended along with the urdu character. Seeing the code would help tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

`s = s+c` locks suspect.

Already tried 
`char c = Translate.translateToUrdu(e.getKeyChar());
doc.insertString(carretPos,new String(c),null);`
?

Comment: i have tried s = Character.toString(c). But same result. The problem basically is the english character is by default displayed in the textComponent before the insertString method is called. I mean if i type 'm' then m is displayed by default, then the converted is shown. So how can i disable the component so that it cannot show the orignal keyboard character.